# Shorcut to group messages by sender in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there any shortcut for this?
Right now what I have to do is right click and select "From".
It would be great if there's any shotrcut out there or some way to assign shortcut.

I tried googling but no luck.